# Google Forms Script send email malfunction

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to make a google form of mine send me the contents of the form via email each time someone fills out the form. I'm using the instructions below, and I've followed them exactly. For some reason, however, when I fill out a form, I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 7, file "Code")"

I look at the line of code right above it, in which "s" is defined and I'm thinking that the problem is that getActiveSpreadsheet is not working for some reason. I think that maybe the script can't find the active sheet. Below is the code snippet which is causing the problem, according to the error email I get from google.

```
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
```

Whole piece of code I'm using;

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
  // Remember to replace this email address with your own email address
  var email = "support@itjones.com"; 

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var subject = "Jones IT - New User Form";

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

  for(var i in headers) 
    message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";     

  // Insert variables from the spreadsheet into the subject.
  // In this case, I wanted the new hire's name and start date as part of the
  // email subject. These are the 3rd and 16th columns in my form.
  // This creates an email subject like "New Hire: Jane Doe - starts 4/23/2013"
  subject += e.namedValues[headers[1]].toString() + " - starts " + e.namedValues[headers[2]].toString();

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you, that makes sense but when I changed my code to use that code snippet I get this error.

2/12/15 4:56 PM sendFormByEmail TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of 
null. (line 9, file "Code") formSubmit 2/12/15 4:56 PM

Line 9 is the line with the function call for sheet.getRange().

```
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WYhDQct8vF-3rlca9dP6lYC2Z23vLLofwJt_DpQU--c');
  var sheet = s.getSheetByName('Jones IT - New User Form (Responses)');
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
```

Is there any way you recommend me changing my code to get the desired result. I don't really care what I have to change, I just want it to email me the contents of the forms when submitted.

Comment: Your variable `sheet` is null.  `getRange()` is a method, trying to be used on the reference to `sheet`.  Your code to get the `sheet` is correct.  So, there is no way I can tell what the real error is.  All I can do is guess.  Maybe it doesn't like the name: `Jones IT - New User Form (Responses)`  I don't know.  Maybe your ID for the spreadsheet is wrong?  It's got to be one of those two things.  Use the debugger to step through your code.  Open this link: [Apps Script Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error, is because the code is being run from a script project bound to the form, and not a spreadsheet.  The script bound to the form has no connection to the spreadsheet.  It can't find the active sheet.  There is no active sheet associated with the form.  The form is associated with the spreadsheet as far as where to submit the data, but not in terms of the code.  You can set a trigger in the spreadsheet to run when the form is submitted, but you might want to get the spreadsheet by ID.

```
function test() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('your SS ID');
  var sheet = s.getSheetByName('your sheet name');
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; 

};
```

Comment: Oops, first time on this site and I put my comment as an answer, my bad. I have another question if you are up to answering it, but it won't fit in this comment box, so I posted it as an answer.